# How to get the total of column values in sqflite in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I want to get the total of the price column values and save it in a variable and return it...I have gone through other posts one of which is the question which i am asking but it was in android native and i am new to sqflite so i couldnt figure out how to write the code. So please help me with suggestions.

this is my code of the columns i am using

```
void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
await db.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE Cart(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT, price TEXT,category 
TEXT,images TEXT)");
print("DB created");
}
```

I am trying to do this

```
Future calculateTotal() async{
var dbClient = await db;// couldnt figure out after this
var cursor = dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) as Total FROM Cart", 
null);
if(cursor.move)
}
```

Comment: use [this](https://kripken.github.io/sql.js/GUI/) for tests for example

Comment: but honestly i would use [sqlite3](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3) tool for learning

Comment: the syntax of sqlite in android are abit different then sqflite in flutter and i am not quite familiar with the syntax

Comment: The same raw SQL string should work though.

Comment: different? no, it is the same sqlite query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://www.techiediaries.com/flutter-sqlite-crud-tutorial/ this should do:

```
Future calculateTotal() async {
  var dbClient = await db;
  var result = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) as Total FROM Cart");
  print(result.toList());
}

int _total;

void _calcTotal() async{
  var total = (await db.calculateTotal())[0]['Total'];
  print(total);
  setState(() => _total = total)
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...  
  Text(_total != null ? _total : 'waiting ...', ... )
```

Comment: it returns an instance of future but i want it as an int

Comment: @BishalDas see https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures, btw `await dbClient.rawQuery(...)` does not return `Future`

Comment: well i am getting the output in the terminal but i am not able to get in the ui

Comment: Perhaps you can post more code that shows how things are related. It's difficult to give advice without knowing what's going on.

Comment: i want to show it in a Text widget but it seems to be a list, so how do i do that?

Comment: this is where i want to display and the below one is my dbhelper class

Comment: The pastebin does not contain the code where `calculateTotal()` is used (called from).

Comment: Future calculateTotal() async {
     var dbClient = await db;
     var result = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) as Total FROM 
      Cart");
    //var value = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT ")
       print(result.toString());
       return result.toList();
       //return result;
      }

Comment: Above is the method and below is the link  https://pastebin.com/4DXpYquU   line 35

Comment: I found the method before, but you told me the result is printed anyway so it should be safe to assume the method works. What does not seem to be working is to display the result. For that I would need to see the code that does that, but I wasn't able to find that code in your pastebin.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FVpQQbtP  this is the link and the line number is 213 i have commented the code Text

Comment: Can you please post what exactly `print(result.toList());` prints?

Comment: [{Total: 1310}]

Comment: I updated my answer with the changes I think you should make. I'd suggest to split up your huge `build()` method into smaller nested custom widgets.

Answer (score 1):

```
Future<List> calculateTotal() async {
  var dbClient = await db;
  var result = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Cart");
  return result.toList();
}

int _total = 0;
List priceList;

void _calcTotal() async{
   priceList = await db.calculateTotal();
   priceList.forEach((price){ _total = _total + price['price'];});
   print(_total);
   setState(() => _total = total);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ...  
   Text(_total != null ? _total : 'waiting ...', ... )
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.